# Is there a way to make a high resolution tree graph using ggplot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I have this data frame and I tried to make a tree graph and save it as a png or jpg with dpi = 300. Could someone help me with that?

```
data= structure(list(Main_Street = c(64L, 64L, 64L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 
270L, 270L, 270L), Event_Type = c("A", 
"B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C"), Blocked_Lanes = c("1", 
"1", "3", ">3", "3", "2", "2", ">3", ">3"), LAYER1 = c(10.95, 
10.48, 12.65, 18.2, 29.09, 15.13, 27.6, 8.4, 18.67), LAYER2 = c(11.9, 
8.62, 10.51, 13.32, 28.28, 13.25, 29.6, 9.35, 21.38)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), groups = structure(list(
    Main_Street = c(64L, 64L, 64L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 270L, 270L, 
    270L), Event_Type = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "A", 
    "B", "C", "A", 
    "B", "C"), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

The output should be something like the picture below. I would like to combine three graphs for the three main streets like the example I gave for 64. Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: Hi Mustafa, you can have a look [at this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/06/creating-flowcharts-with-ggplot2/), it will guide you through creating flowchart with ggplot2.